# Office.context.mailbox.item -> there is no data, it is null for outlook desktop client. Works in OWA

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

The refresh function is called with a button click after everything is loaded.

The error is:
**js error typeerror unable to get property 'internetMessageId' of undefined or null reference**

More Info and link to github issue page: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1402

```
Office.onReady(function () {

refresh: function () {
try {
app.logtext += "\nRefreshing data";
if (!Office.initialize) {
app.logtext += "\nError initializing office..."
} else {
if (Office.context) {
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context true"
}
if (Office.context.mailbox) {
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox true"
}
if (Office.context.mailbox.item) {
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item true"
}
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId" + Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId;
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId" + Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId;
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId" + Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId;
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.subject" + Office.context.mailbox.item.subject;
app.logtext += "\nOffice.context.mailbox.item.itemId" + Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
}
app.internetMsgId = Office.context.mailbox.item.internetMessageId;
app.subject = Office.context.mailbox.item.subject;
app.messageId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
} catch (err) {
app.logtext += "\n JS error" + err;
}
app.settings_egCookie = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-Cookie");
app.settings_userEmail = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-User-Email");
app.settings_userName = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-User-Name");
app.settings_userId = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-User-Id");
app.settings_clientId = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-Client-Id");
app.emailgisticsUser = Office.context.roamingSettings.get("Addin-Emailgistics-User");

    },

}
```